# Convergence in $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence of measurable functions $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup_n \|f_n\|_{L^2} < \infty$ where $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere, is it true that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{ } |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2 dx \rightarrow 0?$$
In other words, does $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ norm?

Comment: Consider $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that it is not true.

Comment: Interestingly, 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{ } |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2 dx \rightarrow 0
$$
doesn't imply that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, either (though it does imply "convergence in measure").

Comment: Yeah that's right. You do, however, get that a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converges a.e.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, as was pointed out in the comments. David Mitra gave perhaps the simplest counter-example $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$. Another class of counter-examples (also with $f=0$) can be had be had by choosing $|f_n(x)|^2$ to be a nascent delta function; for example, $f_n = \sqrt n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$. These show that even replacing the domain of the functions with a compact interval won't make the statement true.